# Попутное замечание

Tags: пунктуация

Один из вопросов, заданных здесь, побудил меня спросить такую вещь: где ставятся, если вообще ставятся, при попутном замечании, которое выделяется тире?
Например, у Пашки Дурова на стене: *"Уже более 10 лет — со времен, когда я был очень небогатым студентом, — я не устаю повторять: деньги переоценены..."* После попутного замечания стоит запятая. Нужна ли он? Одинаковы ли в оформлении предложения: "Мне надоело это терпеть - терплю уже второй год (,) - потому что я уже дошел до ручки" и "Мне надело это - уже второй год - терпеть"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Важно помнить, что вставная конструкция - это осложнение простого предложения. Поэтому знаки в сложноподчиненном предложении остаются, а вставная конструкция внутри предикативной части выделяется.

Читаем внимательно Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации (не в разделе "Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении", а в разделе "Знаки препинания в простом предложении, осложненном вставной конструкцией"):

Вставные конструкции выделяются скобками или тире.

В тексте вставной конструкции сохраняются все необходимые для нее знаки (запятая, восклицательный и вопросительный знаки, многоточие, двоеточие): *Валерия - **так звали девушку, от тоски по которой я сбежал из деревни в Москву,**- слушала меня, мечтательно глядя перед собой.*

При оформлении вставных конструкций в середине предложения встречается употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания. Такое выделение для современных текстов не характерно.

Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака следует отличать от сочетания запятой и тире. необходимого по условиям контекста.  *Жизненный материал - **все то, что  Достоевский называл "подробностями текущей жизни",** - не изучают.*

Значит, в предложении, о котором спрашивает Валентин *"Уже более 10 лет — **со времен, когда я был очень небогатым студентом,** — я не устаю повторять: деньги переоценены..."* знаки препинания расставлены верно. Как, впрочем, и во втором его предложении: **"Мне надоело это терпеть - терплю уже второй год , - потому что я уже дошел до ручки"** Потому что  "перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения или самой вставной конструкции" (Розенталь).
Третье предложение я  переделала бы  в бессоюзное: *"Мне надело это: уже второй год  терпеть"*. Или возможно оставить второе тире как интонационное "Мне надело это: уже второй год -  терпеть"*

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос уточните. Вас невозможно понять. В ваших примерах причин для постановки запятой непосредственно перед тире я не вижу.

А вообще случаи постановки запятой и тире как единого знака исчерпывающе описаны у Розеталя в "Справочнике по литературной правке". Никаких "попутных замечаний" тут нет.

*§113. Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении и в периоде*

*Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставятся в качестве единого знака:*

*1)      перед главным предложением, которому предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного целого на две части, например: Кто виноват из них, кто прав, – судить не нам (Крылов); Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, – мы этого не знаем (Добролюбов);*

*2)      перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное) или дальнейшую часть того же предложения, например: Могло ли не отразиться в литературе это новое общественное движение, – в литературе, которая всегда бывает выражением общества! (Белинский); Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что все без исключения, самые важные, самодовольные люди, – все у него в руках (Л. Толстой); Жизнь его, начавшаяся (в воспоминаниях так чудесно) громадной церковной папертью... и голосом мамы, в котором тысячу раз блестел кремнистый путь и звезда говорила со звездой, – эта жизнь с каждым своим часом наполнялась новым, всё новым значением (Катаев);

3)      в художественной речи в периоде (см. §219, Виды синтаксического повтора, п. 3) (значительном по объему предложении, чаще всего сложноподчиненном, которое делится паузой на две части – повышение и понижение) между его частями, например: Человек принимается за сочинение стихотворения по разным соображениям: чтоб завоевать сердце возлюбленной, чтоб выразить свое отношение к окружающей его реальности, будь то пейзаж или государство, чтобы запечатлеть душевное состояние, в котором он в данный момент находится, чтобы оставить след на земле, – ради этого берется за перо (Иосиф Бродский).

Внутри частей периода, если они значительно распространены, в художественной речи ставится точка с запятой. Реже между частями (членами) периода ставятся запятые, например: Как плавающий в небе ястреб, давши много кругов сильными крылами, вдруг останавливается, распластанный среди воздуха на одном месте, и бьет оттуда стрелой на раскричавшегося у самой дороги самца-перепела, – так Тарасов сын Остап налетел вдруг на хорунжего и сразу накинул ему на шею веревку (Гоголь).*

Случай вставной конструкции, выделяемой парным тире вместо скобок, отсутствует.

Хотя согласен, что тут ещё есть над чем подумать. Нигде, например, не оговариается вопрос о том, что делать, если часть текста непосредственно перед тире заканчивается обособляемой конструкцией. Этот случай - в примере из Дурова, он там запятую ставит, но сомнительно. И ещё, у Розенталя речь идёт о запятой и тире как **едином знаке**, а возможны ли случаи постановки заяптой и тире вместе но не как единого знака не освещается. Но, боюсь, это не наш уровень. *

Comment: То есть если будет конструкция "главная часть - попутное сообщение () - придаточная часть", то на месте () запятая не ставится, так? Просто я не совсем удачно подобрал пример в своем вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

В первом предложении запятая нужна для выделения придаточного предложения. Но я бы исправила тавтологию: убрала второе Я (да и первое можно безболезненно устранить): *Уже более 10 лет — со времен, когда   был очень небогатым студентом, —   не устаю повторять: деньги переоценены...* С другими предложениями мне что-то не совсем понятно, насколько оправдана постановка тире.

Comment: >>>В первом предложении запятая нужна для выделения придаточного предложения.  

А зачем? Вы не будете "выделять" придаточное перед точкой? Перед точкой с запятой? Почему это надо делать перед тире?  
**А если бы вставная конструкция - та, что в парных тире(,) - начиналась бы с придаточного, где запятую ставить?**